# AI A7 Thinker connection with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, gsm, gps

I am trying to connect my A7 to my Arduino Uno but I can't find a way to communicate with it. I searched a lot on the internet to find some schemes but not one of them worked. Here is my actual setup:

```
ARDUINO              A7

PIN 6      <=>       URXD
PIN 7      <=>       UTXD
GND        <=>       GND
5V         <=>       5V
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial myserial(6,7);//RX,TX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  myserial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting...");
}

void loop() {
   delay(1000);
   myserial.println("AT");
   Serial.println(myserial.read());
}
```

I tried by connecting USB instead of 5V, both of them, connecting the POWER pin, or interchange 6 and 7, pressing the power button, with different delays, different baud rates, but I always get the same output on my computer:

```
Starting...
-1
-1
-1
-1
...
```

Sometimes it goes 0 when I plug the USB and press the power button. The LED on the A7 is responding when I press the button and sometimes it powers up the circuit.

I also tried [this solution](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/41850/arduino-connect-uno-to-a7-ai-thinker) with really simple code:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(115200);  
}

void loop() {
}
```

Again with different bauds rates but the compiler outputs an error:

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
...
```

So I don't know what is wrong. Maybe the board is not working but it's most certainly my mistake, so I am asking for your help to solve this puzzle.

Thank you!

Comment: I have no knowledge of an A7, but it looks that you have the RxTx of the serial link as 6 & 7 respectively and on the A7 you have connected 6 to Rx and 7 to Tx.  Normally when a board has a pin marked Tx its means **Its** Tx pin, so you should connect the A7's Tx pin to 6 and Rx to 7.  The programmer from PC to Uno should use pins 0 and 1.

Comment: Quite a few people using A7 and Arduino and working thru challenges at: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=445548.0

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with the exact same thing right now trying to get mine to work. The only help I can give so far is that that avrdude error was solved for me when i stopped trying to upload code to the uno with the a7 powered. think it has to do with the programmer using the same RX/TX ports.

Comment: What is an A7? Is that a board type?

Answer (score 0):

You said...

```
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
```

Those errors are occurring because you are attempting to upload to your Arduino using the same Tx/Rx wires that the software is using and trying to upload on.

**A Possible Fix**

You need to power down the A7.  Possibly pull the ground wire from it when you go to upload your program.  There are alternatives to doing this that are better, but the point is that the A7 is using those wires and keeping them busy.  If the A7 if off then the upload should work.  After uploading, then re-connect the A7 ground wire so it gets power.